# BATCH file reloading autorun buffer

Tags: batch-file, character-encoding, batch-processing, autorun

There are things that we prefer not to understand in order to have an easier life to live.
But this is not something I can choose...

I made a batch file (or macro.doskey) to get the charset code. And it worked perfectly for a long time...

Basically it runs chcp:

```
> chcp
Code page active: 850
```

and then wraps the return before and after the colon 
assigning what comes after to a variable:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%s in ('CHCP') do (
  @ECHO %%t
  IF NOT "%1" == "" (SET %1=%%t)
)
```

For example:

```
> getCHCP.bat myVar
 850
> ECHO %myVar%
 850
```

However it started to lock, waiting for ENTER or displaying several echo messages. For example:

```
> getchcp myVar
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
 850
```

I started to mix until I decided to change the `ECHO %%t` to `ECHO %%s`, and guess what?

[image]

No, is that the Bill Gates skull? Is it an easter egg from Microsoft? A virus?
No, none of that, this is just my autorun's welcome message.

This can be configured in
`<[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor]autorun>`

In my case I called a batch file which, among other things, gives several echos showing this skull on the screen.

- But the question is, why does it act like it reloads the autorun in background
  when I've already opened the command prompt?
- And why does it leave
  everything in the buffer so that `%%s` pulls it again to the (Page code active) ':'?
- And why are
  you giving lots of `ECHO is off` on `%%t` when the only thing after
  **Code page active:** is a number?
- And the most important: How I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious, you already point to the problem.

> this is just my autorun's welcome message.
>
> This can be configured in
> <[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor]autorun>

The line `FOR /F %%s in ('CHCP') ...`  start `CHCP` but that will be done in a **NEW** child cmd.exe instance.
And a **NEW** cmd.exe instance runs the **autorun** command!
Just before it starts your chcp.

You can disable the autorun at all, or add some code to detect the difference between a new cmd.exe instance for the user against a new instance from a `FOR /F`.

Put this code at the start of your autorun batch file

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM *** ALWAYS make a copy of the complete CMDCMDLINE, else you destroy the originial!!!
set "_ccl_=!cmdcmdline!"

REM *** %1 contains only data, when the script itself was called from the command line
if "%~1" NEQ "" (
        goto :direct_call
)

REM *** The check is necessary to distinguish between a new cmd.exe instance for a user or for a "FOR /F" sub-command
if "!_ccl_:~1,-2!" == "!comspec!" (
        REM ***** INTERACTIVE ****
        REM *** Show your skull or something else
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it with a few changes:
```
if not "!_ccl_:~1,-2!" == "!comspec!" (
   exit /b
)
endlocal
```
And after my code with its assignments, presets, macros and batches running in and out.

Comment: With your solution some practices change in programming. Subscripts that would call a new instance are now executed and no longer go back to the main script. This forces you to use call on all subscripts. For example, myScript1.bat contains `CALL myScript2.bat \r\n ECHO with 'call' I back to myScript1 and execute this echo`.  MyScript1.bat executing subscript without CALL: `myScript2.bat \r\n ECHO I never back to myScript1, I need ^&`

Comment: @Zano No, it shouldn't change anything. You always needed `call` when starting another batch file and want that it returns